# PHP image upload security questions

Tags: php, security, upload

I have been having issues with malicious code being uploaded via a form on my website recently.  This form should only allow images to be uploaded.  After doing some reading, I have implemented the following checks.

1. Use getimageresize() on the tmp uploaded file.  If it returns false then kill the upload process.
2. chmod the uploaded image to 644 so that it can't be executed.
3. Uploaded file name is altered (with a random number in front) so it's not exactly the same as what is uploaded by the user.

I've read that checking mime types on server side is also a good idea.  I don't seem to have access to finfo_file() or mime_content_type() on my server though.

Do these sound like good measures to take in order to stop malicious code from being uploaded and executed?  Are there other measures I should be taking?

Comment: Why not just upload them in some place they can't be reached through the web browser?

Comment: They need to be displayed on the website after upload.  I can't seem to access them above webroot from my <img> calls.

Answer (score 0):

Your #1 seems good enough for most people, and it probably is.

However, if you want extra security (at the cost of more memory consumption, I'm afraid), you can save the images in a non-accessible folder (outside the docroot), and write up a simple script that renders the file. This would require for you to load the image into memory though (that's what PHP does), so I wouldn't really suggest it, unless you're really afraid that someone could still hack you.

As I said, your first suggestion should do the trick. Also, #3 is useless, when you insert the image in the DOM, you will expose the new name with the random number :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Re: chmod on the file - Will this actually work to remove all X bits so that if a malicious file did make it up, no one could actually execute it?

Comment: I'm honestly not aware of any methods to run a file on a remote server via a web server, but if there is one, yes, chmodding it should be safe.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm still a bit confused as to how to review files that aren't images, to ensure they are not malicious.  Say I have to allow PDFs to be uploaded, I obviously can't use the getimageresize() function to verify the file.

Comment: My only idea here would be that you need to get a PDF library and call one of its methods, like you do with `getimagesize` for images. If that method returns false, then it's not a valid PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Something to build on what Eduard Luca said. What I would suggest is that you

1. Make sure you are only accepting valid file extension types. This alone can't save you but it will become important if someone uploads a `.php` file
2. Turn off PHP processing for your upload directory. This way you can still directly show images while PHP files will got a 403 error. This can be done via your site config in Apache

   ```
   <Directory "/path/to/upload">
   php_admin_flag engine off
   AllowOverride None
   DirectoryIndex Off
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule \.php$ - [F,L] 
   </Directory>
   ```

Comment: Oh #2 is very interesting... is this done in .htaccess file?  Sorry I'm not super knowledgeable of site config options.  Would this take care of all subdirs within the upload dir, or do they all have to be done separately?

Comment: You definitely can't use `php_admin_flag` with `.htaccess`. It's an Apache level config. http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php